# Joomla: How to display Content of K2 item instead of Title

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, k2

I used this code to display the title of k2 item. The word title in the code should be replace in order to see other output. What should I replace with in order for me to display the Content of k2 item? This is my code

```
<script> jQuery (document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemtest').html('<?php echo $this->item->title;?>');
    }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `title` with `introtext` or `fulltext` if you want to display the full text. Make sure you escape the quotes using the `addslashes` PHP function.

So, you should have something like this:

```
<?php echo addslashes($this->item->introtext);?>
```